# Asymmetric CSS Shadow

Tags: css

How Can I create a shadow like this one?
Only at the bottom corners and gradient.

[image]

Comment: Use image for that

Comment: One easy option would be to have a separate divs for the shadows and position them absolutely based on the parent container.

Comment: @trainoasis But it's not rectangle shadow, more like "tear drop" line of shadow.

Comment: I can see it here [link](http://ammaralhosainy.com/) but I can't extract the code

Comment: He is using images for that: http://static.parastorage.com/services/skins/2.995.7/images/wysiwyg/core/themes/base/liftedshadow_medium.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your CSS like follows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box mybox">
    <h3>My Box</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.box h3{
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 top:80px;
}
.box {
 width:70%;
 height:200px;
 background:#FFF;
 margin:40px auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * MyBox
 * ===============================================*/
.MyBox
{
  position: relative;
}
.MyBox:before, .MyBox:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.MyBox:after
{
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box MyBox">
 <h3>MyBox</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, you may consider using `rgba()` instead of solid color for the shadow thus it will have transparency if there's an image, background color or text beneath it, something like `rgba(0,0,0, 0.7)`

Comment: Yes Sure, we can use it like that as you mentioned i.e. `rgba(0,0,0,0.7)`. Thanks for pointing me @Mi-Creativity

Answer (score 4):

Try see this. Seem to be that you search.

http://codepen.io/jcorpus/pen/xbExKL

there are examples shadow and there is that you search.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box box1 shadow1">
    <h3>Shadow 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
  background:#E6EEF6;
}
.wrap{
  margin-left:20px;
}
.box{
  width:40%;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background-color:white; 
  margin:25px 15px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.box h3{
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:60px;
  color:#fff;
}
.box1{
  background-color: #EBA39E;
}
.shadow1{
  position:relative;
}
.shadow1{
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
/*****************************************************************dashed border
****************************************************************/
.shadow1 h3{
  width:87%;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:6%;
  border:2px dashed #F7EEEE;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.shadow1:before, .shadow1:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  bottom:12px;left:15px;top:80%;
  width:45%;
  background:#9B7468;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 15px #9B7468;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 15px #9B7468;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 15px #9B7468;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
.shadow1:after{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  right: 15px;left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box effect3">
<h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>

    .box h3{
  text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

.effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```